# How can I resize command palette in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Does anyone know how to resize the command palette in Sublime Text 3? It doesn't seem to be an option within the default settings listing. I'm using the ctags plugin and it displays the results in the command palette, which makes it hard to navigate through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've ever been able to tell, the Command Palette is just one of those UI items that can't be resized, along with the auto-complete dropdown and the minimap (beyond a certain size). I've looked all through several themes, and there's just no `"number_of_rows"` or some such setting there. It's possible you might be able to play with the font size, to make it smaller or larger to suit your needs, but I haven't looked into that much.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The only thing you can do is make the padding and font size of each item much smaller. Not ideal though.

Comment: Can you please comment on how to change padding and font size in ST?

Comment: or you can make the font bigger